# Stabilize a Drone into a fixed position using Optical Flow

Tags: computer-vision

Hi i am a beginner in computer vision and i made an program to calculate the translation of X(roll) and Y(pitch) using optical flow and then set the pitch and roll value between 1000-2000 according to the offset, 1500 is the default when position is centered. Now my fear is that this is not enough as you know the drone tilts when it has to move to go to a position and i fear that when this happens i would not get accurate stabilization and would need to obtain also the rotation and not only the translation or is the translation enough?

Comment: If you are writing code to move the drone, you could avoid the rotations. But for stabilization, I think you will need to obtain rotation values, too. However, they are best obtained from a sensor (accelerometer) installed on the drone, not the images.

Comment: @Totoro yes just to correct the drift i can avoid rotations?. to stabilize i might use angle mode in fc config maybe?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Uvj2LYbyAY this is what i am trying to achieve exactly like this video